# How can we sync attribute tables with excel file automatically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, excel

I always export to excel every time I update a shapefile, is there a way of updating excel automatically.

Comment: You cannot edit an existing Excel worksheet they are only READ ONLY. You can export say a shape file's attributes to an Excel table and overwrite?